# Selectbox get all option values jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<select id="selectBox">
    <option value="all">all</option>
    <option value="0">Number 0</option>
    <option value="1">Number 1</option>
    <option value="2">Number 2</option>
    <option value="3">Number 3</option>
    <option value="4">Number 4</option>
    <option value="5">Number 5</option>
    <option value="6">Number 6</option>
    <option value="7">Number 7</option>
</select>
```

If the user select `all` option i need to get all the other option value like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7

My code is:

```
$("#selectBox").live('change', function () {
    var val = this.value;
    if (val == "all") {
        $("#selectBox>option").map(function () {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    }
});
```

Any idea?

Comment: "get all the other option values" ... and what are you going to do with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `.map()` along with `.get()` to accomplish your task,

```
var val=this.value;
var allValues = null;

if (val=="all") {
  allValues = $("#selectBox > option:not(:first)").map(function() {
       return this.value;
  }).get();  //[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
}
```

Full code would be,

```
$("#selectBox").live('change',function(){
    var val=this.value;
    var allValues = null;

    if (val=="all") {
      allValues = $("#selectBox > option:not(:first)").map(function() {
           return this.value;
      }).get();  //[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8m4Tj/11/)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidiq sorry was in a thought of using `.filter()` Corrected accordingly as per your comment..!

Answer (score 3):

you should use `on` as it is recommended and you can get all option like this using `map`:

```
 $("#selectBox").on('change', function () {
    var val = this.value;
    if (val === "all") {

        var all = $("#selectBox>option").map(function () {
        if($(this).val() !== "all")
            return $(this).val();

        });
    }
    console.log(all)

});
```

### OUTPUT:

> **["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]**

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/Q65AS/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`:gt(0)` remove first value either 'all' or 'select'(in my demo)

```
$("#selectBox").on('change', function () {
    var val = this.value;
    var urarr=[]
    if (val == "all") {
        $("#selectBox>option:gt(0)").each(function () {
            urarr.push($(this).val())
        });
    }
    alert(urarr)

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8m4Tj/9/)

Answer (score 2):

update to this:

```
var val = this.value, 
    allValues = '';
if (val=="all") {
     allVals = $("#selectBox > option").map(function() {
          return this.value !== 'all';
     }).get();
     console.log(allVals);
}
```

---

Also instead of `.live()` use it with `.on()` method:

```
$(document.body).on('change', '#selectBox', function(){
    var val = this.value, 
    allVals = '';
    if (val=="all") {
       allVals = $("#selectBox > option").map(function() {
            return this.value !== 'all';
       }).get();
       console.log(allVals);
    }
});
```

---

Since in the latest jQuery libraries `.live()` has been removed so to use the event delegation you need to use `.on()` method to bind events on dynamically generated elements with a specific syntax:

```
$(staticParent).on(event, selector, callback);
```

---

`$(document.body)` can be replaced by the closest static parent of your select like any `div, table etc.`.

---

#### Side note about `.map()`:

I need to mention that `.map()` would not work in the legacy browsers like `ie7`. For this you can use the below mentioned code with use of `.each()` and `.push()`:

```
$(document.body).on('change', '#selectBox', function(){
    var val = this.value, 
    allVals = [];
    if (val=="all") {
       $("#selectBox > option").each(function() {
            allVals.push(this.value);
       });
       console.log(allVals);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaw7X/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#selectBox").on('change',function()
         {
          var val=this.value;
           if (val=="all") {
            $("#selectBox>option").map(function() {
              alert($(this).val());

              });
          }

         });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectBox").live('change',function()
    {
      var val=this.value;
      if (val=="all") {
          var values = $("#selectBox>option").not('option[value=all]').map(function() {
                 return this.value;
          }).get().join();      
        alert(values);
       }

     });
});
```

workind [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/334/)

Answer (score 0):

use **on**  rather than using **live**

```
$("#selectBox").on('change',function()
             {                
              var val=this.value;
               if (val=="all") {
               $("#selectBox  option").each(function() {
    alert(this.text + ' ' + this.value);
                });                
              }    
             });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/dL4PJ/)

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dYah8/43/)**
 use   `filter()`

```
$("#selectBox").on('change', function () {
    var val = this.value;
    if (val == "all") {

        var test = $("#selectBox option").filter(function (i, valu) {

            return val != valu.value
        }).get();

        // if you jquery object 
        alert(test)
        // if you need value do like this
        $(test).each(function (i, val) {
            alert(val.value)
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve same thing using `children` and `map`

```
mapValue= $("select#selectBox").children().not(":first").map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
}).get();
```